# How to open heap dump in netbeans 20

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform, heap-dump

I've heap dump created using [visualvm](https://visualvm.github.io/).

I'm going through this article to analyze heap dump https://www.netbeans.info/profiler_subdomain/docs/help/6.0/heapwalker.html.

But in netbeans 20 version, I don't see **Load Heap Dump..** option in **Profile** action menu.

Below is the Profile Action screenshot
[image: Profile Netbeans 20]

What is correct step to open heap dump in netbeans?